# Police car or ambulance options in CARLA simulator

Tags: ros, simulator, automotive, carla

I'm planning to use CARLA simulator for my project, and I need visual information of siren at emergency vehicles, ON/OFF.

I want to detect/classify {ON siren / OFF siren} of police car or ambulance in emergency situation.

I checked that CARLA simulator supports police car & ambulance assets. My question is that, can I control siren(ON/OFF) of these vehicles?

And also, this is not a important but, can I equip camera at the rear side of my vehicle?

Would be grateful if anybody could let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[Sirens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O8EA.jpg) can be toggled on by setting [carla.VehicleLightState](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_api/#carla.VehicleLightState)
to `Special1` or `Special2`. Use the method `carla.Vehicle.set_light_state`.

To attach cameras, follow the manual [here](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuto_first_steps/#add-sensors).